# Spring Boot Kafka KStream Deserialize Payload

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm new to Kafka Streams. As part of learning processes, I was trying to use Kafka connect with MySQL and publish table data to a topic and then from Spring boot I want to get it and process it.

Using Standalone connect and mysql connector libraries from confluent, I'm able to publish data to topic.
Here is my MySQL table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `kafka_learnings`.`accountdata` (
  `trId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `accType` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `accNumber` INT NULL,
  `trType` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `amount` DECIMAL(50) NULL,
  `trDate` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`trId`));
```

Whenever there is a new row insert based on primary key, I'm getting the data as below in Topic.

```
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"trId"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"firstName"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"lastName"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"accType"},{"type":"int32","optional":true,"field":"accNumber"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"trType"},{"type":"bytes","optional":true,"name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal","version":1,"parameters":{"scale":"0","connect.decimal.precision":"50"},"field":"amount"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp","version":1,"field":"trDate"}],"optional":false,"name":"accountdata"},"payload":{"trId":6,"firstName":"vbncmd","lastName":"WER","accType":"current","accNumber":345789,"trType":"credit","amount":"BNM=","trDate":1685504455000}}
```

The same data I'm getting in my Spring Boot application as well. What I want to achieve is, How to convert the payload message to my POJO class?

I'm using Spring boot 3.1.2

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    StreamsConfig streamsConfig(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        return new StreamsConfig(kafkaProperties.buildStreamsProperties());
    }
}
```

**Component to Process**

```
@Component
public class EventStreamProcessor {

    private static final Serde<String> STRING_SERDE = Serdes.String();

    @Autowired
    void buildPipeline(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
        KStream<String, String> messageStream = streamsBuilder.stream("kafka_transactions-accountdata",
                Consumed.with(STRING_SERDE, STRING_SERDE));
        messageStream.foreach(new ForeachAction<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public void apply(String key, String value) {
                System.out.println("Key :: " + key + " = >>> " + value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With above code, the string data is coming. How to get the payload alone?

```
@Data
public class AccountData{
    
    private int trId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String accType;
    private int accNumber;
    private String trType;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private LocalDateTime trDate;
    
}
```

I tried the below way also.

**AccountDataSerde.java**

```
public class AccountDataSerde extends Serdes.WrapperSerde<AccountData> {

    public AccountDataSerde() {
        super(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>(AccountData.class));
    }
}
```

**EventStreamProcessor.java**

```
@Component
public class EventStreamProcessor {

    private static final Serde<String> STRING_SERDE = Serdes.String();

    @Autowired
    void buildPipelineTransaction(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
        KStream<String, AccountData> messageStream = streamsBuilder.stream("kafka_transactions-accountdata",
                Consumed.with(STRING_SERDE, new AccountDataSerde()));
        messageStream.foreach(new ForeachAction<String, AccountData>() {
            @Override
            public void apply(String key, AccountData value) {

                System.out.println("AccountData ====> " + key + " = >>> " + value);
            };
        });
    }
}
```

But it did not work.

```
AccountData ====> null = >>> AccountData(trId=0, firstName=null, lastName=null, accType=null, accNumber=0, trType=null, amount=null, trDate=null)
```

Also I see the amount field is coming as some encoded value. Is it possible to convert to BigDecimal value?

Answer (score 0):

In your source Kafka connector, set `value.converter.schemas.enable=false`. Otherwise, you need to define your POJO with schema and payload fields, or otherwise parse them first before mapping to the actual value class, for example using map function in KStream

Comment: Thank you. It did not help. As of now I'm defining complete POJO with schema as well. But how to convert the decimal to BigDecimal. The value I'm getting is in String format.? I tried below `BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(new BigInteger(Base64.getDecoder().decode(amount)), 0);` But the problem is if the value inserted in DB is `1234.5` the string format is coming as "BNM=" and on converting to BigDecimal, it is taking the value as 1235 instead of 1234.5. How to get the correct value?

Comment: It should help for new data, so you'll need to empty your existing topic. You'll need to define the value as a string, then parse manually, I believe, such as using a getter